# Is there a way to get User Information in Logs in a Blazor Server application?

Tags: logging, scope, blazor-server-side

Blazor Server Getting User Information in Application Logs

We are trying to get User information such as an email in our logs in a Blazor Server application. The expected result would be that when we log an exception, the log would also include the user information so we can pinpoint who caused the exception. We want to use ILogger in our application and don't really want to rewrite the wheel.

Things we have tried.

1. I've tried using a ITelemetryInitializer to add the user data to the log. This causes an issue because ITelemetryInitializer run in a Singleton / Transient lifecycle but injecting AuthenticationStateProvider which we use to get user data makes it throw an exception

```
Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IConfigureOptions`1[Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration]',
```

and if I make the telemetry initializer scoped I get

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ITelemetryInitializer]' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IConfigureOptions`1[Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration]'.
```

```
 public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider sp;
        public MyTelemetryInitializer(AuthenticationStateProvider sp)
        {
            this.sp = sp;
        }

        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
        }
    }
```

2. I've tried using a circuit manager to keep track of the circuits and the users using those circuits which I thought I could then tie to logs that way. The issue is still the same since the circuit manager is a scoped instance that when I try to use it inside my loggers I get the same error as point 1. I also don't have a good way in code to say, "Get Me My Current Circuit" while in a non-scoped service. The circuit manager I use is based off this YouTube video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWYUIjWKh7w
3. I've tried using IhttpContextAccessor in place of the AuthenticationStateProvider even though it's not recommended by Microsoft. It will actually work to the point that my website runs but it's very inconsistent if the user actually comes across. Sometimes its blank and sometimes I do get the user information so it's not very consistent.
4. I've tried using SeriLogs enrichers to add to the logs. I've based it off the CustomLogEnricher from the last comment in this thread https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25442 but I didn't use the IHttpContextAccessor but the AuthenticationStateProvider instead. That gave me a similar error to point number 1.
5. I've tried to use the scope provider inside these but get the error

```
'GetAuthenticationStateAsync was called before SetAuthenticationState.'
```

for obvious reasons so that didn't work.

6. I've tried log4nets pattern layout converter with the same DI errors I got from the Telemetry Client and SeriLogger.

Similar Issue - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25442

Essentially, I'm just trying to add User Information to our logs while still using ILogger inside our Blazor Server app. Does anyone know of a way we can accomplish this without trying to make our own logger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a solution to the issue. Basically, I use the Error Boundaries to catch any unhandled exceptions then in the Error Content of the Error Boundary I then pass the exception into a view that takes my user service, and a implementation of ILogger (since both live as transient at this point) and then log both together.

The downfall of this is it only works on unhandled exceptions and not exceptions you catch in a try catch block.

```
public class GlobalErrorBoundary : ErrorBoundary
{
    [Inject]
    private IUserService UserService { get; set; } = new NullUserService();
    [Inject]
    private ILogger<GlobalErrorBoundary> Logger { get; set; } = new NullLogger<GlobalErrorBoundary>();

    public Exception Exception { get; set; } = new Exception();
    protected async override Task OnErrorAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        Exception = exception;
        var user = await this.UserService.GetUserDTOAsync();
        this.Logger.LogError(exception, "Unhandled Exception by {user}", user.DisplayName);
        await base.OnErrorAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

And in MainLayout it looks like this

```
<GlobalErrorBoundary @ref="VM.ErrorBoundary">
                        <ChildContent>
                            <CardContainer Title="@VM.Title">
                                @Body
                            </CardContainer>
                        </ChildContent>
                        <ErrorContent>
                            <ExceptionDisplay Exception="@VM.ErrorBoundary.Exception" Recover="@VM.ErrorBoundary.Recover"></ExceptionDisplay>
                        </ErrorContent>
                    </GlobalErrorBoundary>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpContextAccessor` in an `ITelemetryInitializer` to add to trace and exception telemetry, and then request middleware to add to the request telemetry. You can get the `RequestTelemetry` from the context using

```
httpContext.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>();
```

Comment: Sadly I've tried httpcontextaccessor and it does allow the project to build and run, but when it actually logs it only catches the user information sometimes. Most of the time it will come back with no user information.